# Animate text change over time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to animate text change over time that never stops.

I've found this simple example with jquery:

```
      $(function() {

    $('#header-text-change').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).text('Some other text!').fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

Now I need to have more than one predefined text and that animation loops forever.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the example in relation to what you want to do? could you post that code please? It's not a coding service.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I know it's not. I need to animate text change in single HTML element with ID header-text-change. So you specify few strings that change over time to be content in specified HTML element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function to loop every N milliseconds.

**Look this code snippet:**

*This example reset the `index` variable to `0` when hits TEXTS.length*

```js
var TEXTS = ["Some other text!", "Lord of the Rings", "Avengers", "Whatever text"];

var index = 0;

$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#header-text-change').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).text(TEXTS[index++]).fadeIn(500);
      if (index === TEXTS.length)
        index = 0
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header-text-change">
  Hellow World!!
</h1>
```

See? now your code is looping, in this case every one second (1000ms).

Answer (score 1):

```
function fadeout(){$('#header-text-change').fadeOut(undefined,changeText)}
function changeText(){
    // implements your logic for changing the text
    fadein();
}
function fadein(){$('#header-text-change').fadeIn(undefined,fadeout)}
```

You call fadeout and it loops using the callbacks( and they are named so you can reference them). Passing undefined as the first argument to fadeOut/fadeIn will use the default value of 400ms, you could change that by passing a variable that stores how long you want the animation to take.